# Cannot find a question with title when I mark as duplicate

Tags: bug, search, exact-duplicates

I try to flag a question as duplicate. When I add the title on the search bar, it doesn't return the one I want to mark with.

The question I want to vote for closing

[How to merge two csv files using multiprocessing with python pandas](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12786/how-to-merge-two-csv-files-using-multiprocessing-with-python-pandas)

And the question I try to find during the voting process

[merge 2 dataframe with Memory Error](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/45550/merge-2-dataframe-with-memory-error/57198#57198)

This is what I get

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The Stack Exchange search is notoriously weak.  The duplicate search even more so. A reliable work around that I use is to get the question ID and use it in the search box.

You can get the question ID from the address bar:

[image: Fetching Question ID]

Then you can use the ID in the duplicate close selection search box:

[image: Entering Question ID]

Comment: This.  Been there multiple times. So, can vouch for Stephen's approach :D